# ArchLinux pacman updates on Arm

Tags: arch-linux, gcc, pacman, chrome-os, chrome-book

I have ArchLinux embedded in userspace on my Samsung Series 3 Chromebook. The version of GCC I have installed via pacman is 4.7.2. I'd like a newer version, and the package database [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=gcc&maintainer=&flagged=) shows that the Core repository has GCC 4.8.0-4. However, when I run `sudo pacman -Syu`, I am told there is nothing to do. I'm happy to be patient, though as a newcomer to ArchLinux, I wonder if someone can tell me why my version is not yet 4.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ARM package](https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs/tree/master/core/gcc) has only just been updated; it likely just hasn't propagated to your mirror yet.

You can change your mirror in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` and then force a rsync of your local database with `pacman -Syyu`. Or you could just wait for the package to arrive on your current mirror.

Comment: I'm still with GCC 4.7.2. In my `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` I'm setting Server to http://mirror.archlinuxarm.org/armv7h/core/ Browsing there shows only GCC 4.7.2. Other mirrors are listed below (in mirrorlist) by country, but behave similarly.

Comment: By the way, isn't it `pacman -Syu`?

Comment: @user7543 `-Syyu` forces a resync of the local db...

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. Even so, I'm still with GCC 4.7.2.